# What are ListViewChartInstances?

Tags: soap-api, standard-objects, describesobject, spring15

In v33.0, I see a new object, called `ListViewChartInstance` when describing all objects through SOAP API. However, in the [Salesforce Spring '15 Release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring15_release_notes.pdf) there's not a single word on them. Does anyone have some more info on this object?

Thanks in advance!

Haris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This object isn't available for public consumption yet. It appears to be charts that can be displayed from a list view. You're not likely to get any more of a "real" answer than this, because anyone that could tell you definitely would be under NDA and/or Safe Harbor agreements, and everyone else would only be able to speculate about what it might be for. Right now, it's clearly not meant to be seen, because even one of the field labels currently reads "TODO, use alias." From what I found out about it, it appears they're adding real-time charts to list views, perhaps as a lightweight dashboard option. I'm sure it'll have limits, like perhaps a 2,000 record limit or something (hopefully more reasonable, closer to 50k). It has a selection of chart types available, a field that represents the query (possibly just for debugging purposes, but it'd be cool if we could write our own query), and a lookup field to the ListView object. There's absolutely no way for an outside to experiment, because the object can't be queried (you'll get an error), nor can you perform any DML on it. They will probably hotfix this so it's no longer visible soon. Hiccups like this occasionally happen, although they do try to keep this to a minimum (hidden profiles, for example, or other entities have occasionally leaked through to the UI/API).